# How do I draw special Circle in Qt5?

Tags: qt5, ellipse, qpainterpath

I want to draw a special segmented circle like the below image.

But I cannot understand how to draw an arc or ellipse using the 
`setDashPattern`.

Image:
[image]

At first, I thought that just drawing a colored circle and drawing a transparent rect or line to covered it would work.
But it just passed though...

Second, I tried the below code,

```
QPicture pi;
QPainter p(&pi);
QPen pen(Qt::red);

qreal space = 6;
qreal ine = 99;
pen.setDashPattern(QVector<qreal>() <<
line << space << line << space <<line << space);

p.drawRect(0,50, 100, 100);
p.end();
```

But this is not what I want it to do.

Does anyone know how to draw rings like this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to to set a clip path to the painter and draw two complete circles.

You can create a `QPainterPath` that covers the areas where the circles need to be drawn (black areas). Than set this path to the painter using `QPainter::setClipPath()`. Finally draw the two circles.

See:

- [QPainter clipping](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#clipping)
- [QPainter::setClipPath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#setClipPath)
- [QPainterPath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html)

Comment: Thank you for good keyworkd(ClipPath)..But I think that I have to make a path that black line's path... isn't it ? I think that it needs arc's path.. If I can make this black arcpath, then it is more easy to drawing..

Comment: Yes you are right, I will correct. You can create a path that cover the black areas, adding for examples some polygons, like some "cake slices".

Comment: Or you can add a big rectangle to the path that covers all area, and than some polygons as "holes" that cover the "white" areas. Be sure to use Qt::OddEvenFill as fill rule of the path